# inserting data from multiple text boxes to single column

Tags: php, mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SieTe.png)i want to insert multiple text box value in to a single column in a table at a time

it should b like there should be name and infront of name there are text boxes to enter age of the students
so when we submit then the age entered infront of the student name it will get stored in the table with student names and ages.
(multiple students data feeding at a time)

Comment: post the html form you tried

Comment: You should clarify and/or break down into smaller chunks what you are trying to do. For what I've read, I think the answer has already been given multiple times in many threads...

Comment: Are the names are stored in database and you are displaying them in a form and each textarea after them for age. Post your code here to get ans

Comment: mamta mam heres the code

Comment: $sql="insert into adprice(tendername,companyname,qprice)values
('$tendername','$companyname','$qprice')";

Comment: <?php
   $sql="select * from adcomp where tendername='$tendername'";
  $q = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
   while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($q,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
     ?>
   
  <tr>
   
   
  </tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $r['companyname']; ?>" name="companyname" readonly="true"</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="qprice"></td>
  
  <?php
   }
   
   ?>
 <tr>
   <td colspan="3" align="center">
  
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

Comment: saurabh i have answered try that but first change table name fields name according to yours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Try this change `table` name and `column` name according to yours.
Also i have `query` all data of `table` this will `update` all fields age if already age exist and you fill again in form. So either apply `where` `condition` in your query so that it filter only name which does not have price or add value field in form which display age if exist in `database`.(This is according to code you provided in comment)

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password,$mysql_database) or die("Could not connect database");
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from user");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){    
    $sql = "UPDATE user SET age = (CASE name ";
        foreach($_POST['age'] as $key=>$value){
        $sql = "UPDATE user SET age = '$value' where name = '$key'";
        mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    }
    $success = "updated successfully";  
}
if(isset($success) && !empty($success)){    
    echo '<h3>'.$success.'</h3>';
}
echo '<form method="post">';
echo '<table>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){?>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" name="name" readonly="true"></td>
           <td><input type="number" name="age[<?php echo $row['name']; ?>]" placeholder='enter age'></td>
        </tr>       

<?php } ?>
<tr><td colspan="2">
 <input type="submit"   name="submit" value="Save"></td></tr>

 </table>
</form>
```

Comment: mam i want to update one remark also where name and qprice are updated

Comment: Can you explain clearly what is remark field.if it is in database then what is its type ,default value and what you want to store in it.

Comment: and it is updating all rows where name is same i want update qprice where tendername=$tendername and companyname=$companyname

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your example but if you want to store multiple values in a single database column, you can pass these values into an array and encode it with [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php). After reading the values from the database you can transform it back to an array with [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php).

Answer (score 0):

Use json_encode to encode the content and then store it in database field and when you retrieve the value then use json_decode

```
$form_data_json = json_encode( $_POST );
```